# React Native - console.log and network commands are not working

Tags: react-native, scrollview, console.log

I've a strange problem in app I'm currently coding.

**Here is the story of the app :**

I've used React Native's ScrollView as a horizontal slider,
I display maximum 5~6 slides so I don't need to use FlatList for this.

Slides are actually records coming from the database so actually they are some dynamic components
and slider works as expected.

In every slide,  there are also are some option buttons (Touchables) to send data to the server.
When the user presses a button app is opening a modal window to confirm and then sending some data to server.

Until now all is okay.

**The Problem :**

But in some slides of the slider I'm having a strange problem :

"console.log" commands and also network commands to send data to server is not working.

On the screen, I see Buttons(Touchables) are working and also the modal I've coded is also appearing & disappearing according to the state variables. But somehow console.log commands and also network commands are not even executed.  Since I can't log anything it's also hard to understand the problem.

Is there anyone had a similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I can but code is a long one, it contains many sub components. I'm not sure which part to post here.
I just wanted to know if anyone have encountered a "console.log" is not working but actually the screen components are working.

Comment: Yeah, i usually just remove all unnecessary components before I upload and just show the components that I know are affected. The issue could be so many things especially when the code is not here

Comment: I encountered this but a while ago and in my case it was solved either after restarting the bundle and everything either after digging a bit into code and finding the issue (I would try to see if the console.logs are printed when the modal shows/hides to see if it's the first case I mentioned or is something else)

Comment: Thanks diana,  after spending a little time on the app I've noticed that actually it's not happening only on some slides.  Once it starts to happen , app starts to work abnormally and continues without executing any console.log and freezing while there is a call to the server. So actually it's crash without any log on console. I'm currently researching about garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved this problem, wanted to share my experience here.

In the app I was making post requests to the backend with Axios,
but I wasn't interested in the result of this post requests,
they were just log records so the result of backend calls weren't important.

So I didn't use any "await" command or didn't code anything like Promise.then / catch,
just posted with Axios and scrolled to another slide in my app without waiting for the backend.

After the 8th Axios post, app started not to work.
It seems like working .. touchable effects , modals even navigation works
but nothing else was working.  Event console.log commands weren't working.

It's an interesting behavior of React Native , but I've understood the situation after reading the blog below :

https://medium.com/@rotemmiz/react-native-internals-a-wider-picture-part-1-messagequeue-js-thread-7894a7cba868#

Basic reason was that in the backend (NodeJS) I didn't return any response,
there wasn't any command like res.send("success") .. so frontend React Native app was waiting for the response.. event if I didn't use any await or Promise it was still trying to get the response and after the 7-8 call it was blocking the main thread.

If there is a way to configure Axios not to wait for the backend to answer for the post request, please write here.